# Angular 9 how to keep component state after back to previous page?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-state-managmement

I am new to Angular. I am using Router for switch the screen.. Like this

```
this._router.navigate(['a_page'],{state: {data: moredata})
```

and get the state in a_page constructor like this

```
this._router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
```

But if i back from a_page and then forward using browser forward button the extras.state was null. I don't know how to do this in best way, please suggest the idea. Thank you.

Comment: you should try exploring `ngRx` or any state management library

Comment: using state management library is good or have any other standard method?

Comment: You should use ngRx `Subject` to preserve the result instead of playing with router.

Comment: well if it's small chunk of data like `id`  .. try  `localStorge` ... but if it's a large amount of data better go with state management library

Comment: If you wish I can give you example

Comment: Isn't it a little anti-pattern to pass states between pages? If you reload the webpage your data is lost anyway...

Comment: @KamranKhatti Could you please share any example links?

Comment: @Sabish.M shared example checkout my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use singleton services wi th a Subject in order to share data between components (a state management library isn't required).

Create a service using angular-cli : `ng generate service service-name`

Inject the service into the constructor of the components which need to share the same data :

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {}
```

Inside your service, declare a subject which will be responsible to keep the data (a BehaviorSubject is a good idea as it's initialized with a value) :

```
data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>('foo');
```

To change its value from a component, use the `next()` method on it :

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {}

update(): void {
  this.service.data.next('bar');
}
```

Then in order to get the last value in any component (or service/directive...), subscribe to the BehaviorSubject and do whatever you want with the value :

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.data.subscribe(value => {
  // do whatever
  });
}
```

Each time the `next()` method will be used somewhere in your application, any subscription somewhere else will get this new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use typescript accessor [setter and getter](https://medium.com/@janithkasun/typescript-accesor-beautiful-getters-and-setters-d60bf5292b4d) to achieve desired result.

create a service where you set and get the value.

**state.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
 _state;

 get state() {
  return this._state;
 }

 set state(data) {
  this._state = data
 }
}
```

get and set can be achieve from any component

```
export class StateComponent {
 // inject state service to access set get methods
 constructor(private service: StateService) {
  this.service.state =  { data: moredata }; // setting state

  console.log(this.service.state); // getting state from anywhere 
}
```

Hope this works.